# Phoenix Framework with code reloading enabled, is pretty slow on Windows

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I newbie to Phoenix Framework and Elixir and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

If I create a new project with `mix phoenix.new testproject`, it works as expected. I run cowboy on Windows 10 with `mix phoenix.server` and requests are served fast.

But I have a little modified project, that works very slow when `code_reloader` option is enabled in `dev.exs` config file. A request cant take minutes. If I set this option to false, it works pretty well.

I have replaced brunch by gulp to generate all priv assets, but as far I know, I haven't changed much more (perhaps by mistake).

You can see my ugly project [on GitHub](https://github.com/rubenfa/schoolmaster)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have only a Mac, but I cloned your repo and changed `code_reloader` to `true`. I don't experience the slowness. What exact version of Erlang, Elixir and Phoenix do you use? Have you run `mix compile` before `mix phoenix.server`?
I also get this error: `[error] Could not start node watcher because script "node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js" does not exist. Your Phoenix application is still running, however assets won't be compiled. You may fix this by running "npm install".` And `npm install` doesn't fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your help @tkowal. I have gulp installed so whatcher is working without problem in my machine. In fact, if I change any js or css file, it is reloaded. I guess it is a problem with my GitHub repo. If I'm not wrong (I'm not in my machine right now), I have Elixir 1.2 and Erlang 18 installed

Comment: It may be slow because we or gulp may be pooling the operating the system. Can you paste the information that shows up right after you run "mix phoenix.server"? Does it print any warnings or errors? Also, does it happen on every request or only when you change some file?

Comment: I have Windows 10 with Elixir 1.2 and Erlang 18; if I get a chance I'll see if I can repro your behavior on a plain Phoenix install.

Comment: Do you have this in in your mix.exs file `{:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},`? How is code_reloader different than live_reload?

Comment: For what it's worth I just tried modifying web/static/js/app.js and the page reloaded immediately.

Comment: I don't know why, but it is working fine now. I will carry out more tests. Maybe the problem was in my computer. Or maybe I'm the problem. Thanks all for your help.